# Facebook graph api - does not return shares for some posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have problem with graph api since about 2 months. Api does not return shares count for same posts from my fanpage. All posts has the same restrictions.

My endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{fanpageId}/posts?access_token={token}&fields=application,created_time,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true),shares,name,link,from,type,picture&limit=100
```

I have no idea why...

Comment: Are you using a page access token that belongs to a user who is an admin on the given page? There has been a change in the Graph API where you need to satisfy this condition if you want to access any data pertaining to a user from a page. https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2017/11/07/marketing-api-v211/

Comment: I do not think this is the case because there is no shares data only for some posts.